# IEnumerable<T>.Count() vs List<T>.Count with Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, extension-methods

I am retrieving a list of items using Entity Framework and if there are some items retrieved I do something with them.

```
var items = db.MyTable.Where(t => t.Expiration < DateTime.Now).ToList();
if(items.Count != 0)
{
    // Do something... 
}
```

The `if` statement could also be written as

```
if(items.Count() != 0)
{
    // Do something... 
}
```

In the first case, the `.Count` is a `List<T>.Count` property. In the second case, the `.Count()` is `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` extension method.

Although both approaches achieve the same result, however, is one more preferred than the other? (Possibly some difference in performance?)

Comment: `Enumerable.Count` has the advantage that you can change the type of the sequence later without breaking the code. But note that `Any` is better since `Count()` enumerates the entire sequence if it's no a collection whereas `Any` stops at the first item. It's also more readable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter but it has disadvantage if you will not change type of sequence :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: The only disadvantage is that it's often used even if `Any` would be better (see my edit).

Comment: @TimSchmelter for `Any()` you will pay with enumerator creation. On the other hand `Count()` will simply read `Count` property of `ICollection<T>`

Comment: `Any` is better IF it's a `!= 0` comparison.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: That's micro optimization. Apart from that, using `Count()` on an entity framework query that returns all records just to know if there is one record, _that_ is really inefficient. Also, `Any` suggests that i want to know if there is an item, not how many items there are. So it's also more readable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: would you then suggest doing `IQueryable<T>.Count()` to determine if there are any records. And if there are then issue another query and do what I did above (`IQueryable<T>.ToList()`) to obtain the items?

Comment: @TimSchmelter take a look on sample code. It is method body. It is `List<T>`. I usually don't write methods longer than 10-15 lines. I believe you too. So, in such small context there is no benefit of writing abstract code which will work with any `IEnumerable`. Use power of collection you have. It's not a big deal to change two lines of code in method body if collection type will change (it rarely does)

Comment: @mikhairu nope, in that case you will have two queries to server

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Here it is a list now, maybe OP changes the code and removes the `ToList` without changing `Count()` to `Any`. Many people use `Count` when they actually mean `Any`(`Count > 0`) with `IEnumerable<T>` wihtout knowing the consequences.

Comment: @TimSchmelter in that case he will have two queries to server, without any warnings. Simple `Count` will complain of collection type change. And my previous comment was not about `Any()` usage - it was about writing flexible abstract code in very small contexts

Comment: It's important to understand that once you throw the `ToList` in there, you're no longer getting the benefit of deferred query. Instead of working with a LINQ-to-Entities provider, you're now working with LINQ-to-Objects. There are a number of important differences, such as Count() deferring to the underlying implementation instead of being translated to SQL, as well as string comparisons no longer being case insensitive.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Enumerable.Count<T>` (the extension method for `IEnumerable<T>`) just calls `Count` if the underlying type is an `ICollection<T>`, so for `List<T>` there is no difference.

`Queryable.Count<T>` (the extension method for `IQueryable<T>`) will use the underlying query provider, which in many cases will push the count down to the actual SQL, which *will* perform faster than counting the objects in memory.

If a filter is applied (e.g. `Count(i => i.Name = "John")`) or if the underlying type is not an `ICollection<T>`, the collection is enumerated to compute the count.

> is one more preferred than the other?

I generally prefer to use `Count()` since 1) it's more portable (the underlying type can be anything that implements `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>`) and 2) it's easier to add a filter later if necessary.

As Tim states in his comment, I also prefer using `Any()` to `Count() > 0` since it doesn't have to actually count the items - it will just check for the existence of one item.  Conversely I use `!Any()` instead of `Count() == 0`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the underlying collection and where Linq will be pulling from. For example if it's SQL then using `.ToList()` will cause the query to pull back the entire list, and then count it. However, the `.Count()` extension method will translate it into a SQL `COUNT` statement on the database side. In which case there will be an obvious performance difference.

For just a standard List or Collection it's as stated in D. Stanley's answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it depends on what's going on inside the `if` block.  If you're simply doing the check to determine whether to perform a sequence of operations on the underlying enumeration, then it's probably not needed in any event. Simply iterate over the enumeration (omitting `ToList` as well).  If you're not using the collection inside the `if` block, then you should avoid using `ToList` and definitely use `Any` over any `Count/Count()` method.

Once you've performed the `ToList` then you're no longer using Entity Framework and I expect that `Count()` is only marginally slower than `Count` since, if the underlying collection is `ICollection<T>` it defers to that implementation.  The only overhead would be determining whether it implements that interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338038.aspx

> Remarks:
>   If the type of source implements `ICollection<T>`, that implementation is used to obtain the count of elements. Otherwise, this method determines the count.

Comment: Could you elaborate on `If you're simply doing the check to determine whether to perform a sequence of operations on the underlying enumeration, then it's probably not needed in any event.`?

Comment: Well, if your check is simply `if (items.Any()) { foreach (var item in items) { .... } }`, then you don't need to check first. If there are no elements in the collection, the `foreach` loop works just as well.